# Pandas time Zone Conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

**Problem:**

I have a data frame as example:

df:

```
a   b                      c      d
1   2020-01-20 01:00:00    32     jajskdn
2   NaN                    23     2aksn
3   2020-05-20 02:00:00    asjn   sdn
4   NaN                    sd     cas
7   NaN                    nf     cka
```

I m trying to apply `tz_convert` as below

```
df[b] = df[b].dt.tz_convert['America/New_York']
```

I'm getting below error as we have `NaN` values in the dataframe:

```
Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tz_convert'
```

How to solve the above issue by handling null values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you can try:

```
# just choose the non-null rows first
df1 = df.loc[df['b'].notna()]

df1['b'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['b']).dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('America/New_York')

# combining it again with null/NaN value rows to get the converted final df
df_converted = pd.concat([df1, df.loc[df['b'].isna()]]).sort_values(['a'])
```

Output:

```
   a                          b     c        d
0  1  2020-01-19 20:00:00-05:00    32  jajskdn
1  2                        NaN    23    2aksn
2  3  2020-05-19 22:00:00-04:00  asjn      sdn
3  4                        NaN   sdn      cas
4  7                        NaN    nf      cka
```

We would need to explicitly convert it to a datetime field and also localize it before converting it to some other timezone.

Hope this helps.

Also, the error that you were getting was because of syntactical mistake while calling tz_convert with square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

you can drop nan rows from a dataframe by using:

```
    df = df.dropna()
```